# Calculating an integral $\int_{0}^{1}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}dx$

Tags: integration

I confused for calculating $$\int_{0}^{1}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}dx$$
one solution that I guess is:
$$1^{n}=(x+1-x)^{n}=\binom{n}{k}x^{k}(1-x)^{n-k}$$
so $$x^{k}(1-x)^{n-k}=\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}$$
finally $$\int_{0}^{1}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}dx=\frac{(n-k)!k!}{n!}$$

but I saw elsewhere that the answer is $$\frac{(n-k)!k!}{(n+1)!}$$
I confused which one is correct??!!

Comment: You forget a sum: $$1^n=(x+1-x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k} x^k(1-x)^{n-k}.$$

Comment: To pursue on your idea, introduce some parameter $t>1$ and consider $$\int_0^1(tx+1-x)^ndx=\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}t^kx^k(1-x)^{n-k}dx=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}I_{k,n}t^k,$$ where $I_{k,n}$ denotes the integral you are interested in. Then the change of variable $u=tx+1-x$ shows the LHS is $$\int_1^tu^n\frac{du}{t-1}=\frac1{n+1}\frac{t^{n+1}-1}{t-1}=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^nt^k,$$ hence, by identification, $${n\choose k}I_{k,n}=\frac1{n+1},$$ end of the proof.

Answer (score 4):

For each $k$, define $I_k$ as $I_k=\int_0^1x^k(1-x)^{n-k}dx$.

Using integration by parts, you'll get $I_{k+1}=\frac{k}{n-k}I_k$. Using the initial condition $I_0=\int_0^1(1-x)^ndx$ conclude.

Comment: Thanks a lot. but it should be k+1 in the fraction (derivative of $x^{k+1}$)

Answer (score 1):

I'll be using [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) to sove the problem.

The integral:$$\large \int_{0}^{1}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}dx$$

$$\large =B(k+1,n-k+1)$$

where, B(x,y) is beta function.

$$\large =\frac { \Gamma \left( k+1 \right) \Gamma \left( n-k+1 \right)  }{ \Gamma \left( n+2 \right)  } $$

$$\large =\frac { k!\left( n-k \right) ! }{ \left( n+1 \right) ! } $$

Comment: Why do you delete your answer, and then add one that is the same?

Comment: This is more or less equivalent to saying that one knows the answer hence one knows the answer.

Comment: Certainly not. One can definitely answer this question in a way which is not equivalent to "one knows the answer hence one knows the answer" (see my comment on main for an option).

Comment: Huh? No idea how your last comment applies to the question, to your answer or to the point I made. Care to explain?

Comment: Not in general, of course, this depends on the cases: in the present case, yes this is what you did (as you admitted). Sorry but why are we even discussing this?